# How do I disable the insert key on Wayland?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, wayland

How can I disable the insert key on Ubuntu 22.04 in Wayland?

In X11, it was simple:

```sh
# Figure out what keycode is mapped to insert key.
xmodmap -pke | grep -i insert

# Disable it.
echo "keycode 90 =" >> ~/.Xmodmap
```

Is there no similar remapping functionality in Wayland?

Answer (score 1):

It seems Wayland lacks this configurability.

Here's the workaround solution I'm using via [rvaiya's `keyd`](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd):

##### Install `keyd`

```sh
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd
cd keyd
make && sudo make install
sudo systemctl enable keyd && sudo systemctl start keyd
```

##### Remap the `insert` key in `/etc/keyd/default.conf`

`sudo vi /etc/keyd/default.conf`:

```sh
[ids]

*

[main]

# Disable insert key.
insert = noop
```

Then reload `keyd`:

```sh
sudo keyd reload
```